# How does nmap distinguish closed ports from filtered ports

Tags: monitoring, tcp

Let's suppose we are doing a TCP connect scan.

a nmap scan on google returns the following output :

> PORT    STATE SERVICE
>
> 80/tcp  open  http
>
> 443/tcp open  https

However, if I try to open a socket with netcat or telnet on google.com on the port 12 for example, netcat or telnet hangs indefinitely.

Nmap detects the port 12 (and other ports other than 80 or 443) as closed but initiating a TCP connection to them does not instantly closes.

How can nmap know those ports are not filtered but closed ?

Comment: By default(though there's more to that algorithm) the output you'll get from nmap is only the opened ports, not the closed or filter'ed ones. nmap -p 12 www.google.com should normally show it as filtered.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With nmap scan, you usually get 3 states:

- Open - remote computer responded with a SYN/ACK to your SYN
- Closed - remote computer rejected your connection attempt with a RST packet
- Filtered - nothing came back, timeout occured

Opening a netcat to port 80 and waiting will not do anything. Port 80 (usually) means a http server is listening on the other side, and it is waiting for a HTTP command (until its own timeout). After netcatting to port 80, try sedinng a `GET /` to see if you get a reply (probably a http error).

Answer (score 8):

A closed port is a port that doesn't have any software listening on it, so an attempt to make a connection to that port on that system will result in the system sending back a TCP RST packet.

A filtered port, on the other hand is typically a port that is blocked by a firewall in the network path, so an attempt to make a connection to that port on that system will result in nothing coming back at all...not even a TCP RST...so a connection attempt will sit there until TCP times out the attempt to connect.

Comment: This is true but does not answer my question. Open a netcat on google.com on port 42, you won't get an RST packet, but nmap marks this port as closed.

Comment: My nmap to google.com including port 42 returns it as filtered, not closed.

Comment: My bad, I thought all ports not shown were closed, but it depends on the global result.